# How to assign the value of Select to other variable in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP)" />
</td>    
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@NACRES)" />
</td>
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select=" First <TD> Value divided by Second)" />
</td>
```

I have a problem with printing third TD which is the Division of first two. how do i do? How to get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your values in separate variables and refer them later.

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
    <xsl:variable name="vFirst" select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSecond" select="sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@NACRES)"/>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vFirst"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vSecond"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vFirst div $vSecond"/>
    </td>
```

Comment: Not Loaded properly.. but still thanks :)..... instead of tht one i used 
<xsl:value-of select="round((sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@TBONUSP) div sum(//Form[@PRONME = current()/@PRONME]/@NACRES))*10000) div 10000"/>

Comment: @Rocky, that's another possible solution, but in that way you will go to perform the sums twice (4 times).

Comment: You are right ofcourse... but method u gave me not worked out with me.....Don't know why..!!!!!

Comment: @Rocky you are welcome. It might depends by your XSLT processor.